# Can I use the Char variable as an integer value in C?

Tags: c, variables, char

I want to do what I stated in the question. Is this possible?

For example:

```
char number=5;
char number_two=number*3;
char x=number_two/15;
```

Can I do the arithmetic above?And if the answer to all of these is yes, would a char variable have a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 255?

THANKS!...

Comment: Implementation- and target-dependent.  But likely will need `unsigned char` to represent values > 127.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you ask.  However, `char` could be a signed type depending on the implementation you're using.  If you want to guarantee you get a range 0 to 255, you will need to use `unsigned char` type.

Comment: Whether `char` is signed is implementation-defined.

Comment: "Whether char is signed is implementation-defined." what does this mean?

Comment: @egekaygusuz: The C standard says a C implementation (typically a compiler, supporting software, and a system to run on) may make the `char` type either signed or unsigned. “Implementation-defined” means the C standard requires the C implementation to state in its documentation which choice it makes.

Answer (score 2):

The `char` type is an integer type, like `short`, `int`, and `long`. It is implementation-defined whether it is signed or unsigned.

If it is signed, it must support a range from −127 to +127, inclusive. If it is unsigned, it must support a range from 0 to 255, inclusive. (So a common range it must support whether it is signed or not is 0 to 127.)

If you want to guarantee a range of 0 to 255, you should use `unsigned char`. (A C implementation may also provide larger ranges for `char` and `unsigned char`.)